# Sylius - How to add a custom promotion action?

Tags: sylius

I have followed the tutorial listed [enter link description [here](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-promotion-action.html#register-the-action-as-a-service).

However, when i try to add a promotion with this action, i get this error:

```
Could not load type "AppBundle\Promotion\Action\CheapestProductDiscountPromotionActionCommand"
```

Upon further investigation, `CheapestProductDiscountPromotionActionCommand.php` goes through the following code block in `FormRegistry.php`:

```
if (class_exists($name) && in_array('Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface', class_implements($name))) {
    $type = new $name();
} else {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Could not load type "%s"', $name));
}
```

From what i can gather, it is checking if `CheapestProductDiscountPromotionActionCommand.php` implements `FormTypeInterface` but Im not entirely sure why? I thought `CheapestProductDiscountConfigurationType` extends `AbstractType` which implements `FormTypeInterface`? Maybe Im wrong but i would of thought that `CheapestProductDiscountPromotionActionCommand.php` should not be going through the above code block?

My stack trace is as follows:

```
Stack Trace

    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php at line 87   +

    at FormRegistry ->getType ('AppBundle\\Promotion\\Action\\CheapestProductDiscountPromotionActionCommand')
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php at line 83   +

    at FormFactory ->createNamedBuilder ('UK_WEB', 'AppBundle\\Promotion\\Action\\CheapestProductDiscountPromotionActionCommand', array(), array('auto_initialize' => false, 'label' => 'UK Web Store', 'currency' => 'GBP'))
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php at line 47   +

    at FormFactory ->createNamed ('UK_WEB', 'AppBundle\\Promotion\\Action\\CheapestProductDiscountPromotionActionCommand', array(), array('auto_initialize' => false, 'label' => 'UK Web Store', 'currency' => 'GBP'))
    in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Form/EventSubscriber/BuildChannelBasedPromotionActionFormSubscriber.php at line 114   +

    at BuildChannelBasedPromotionActionFormSubscriber ->createConfigurationFieldForChannel (object(Channel), 'AppBundle\\Promotion\\Action\\CheapestProductDiscountPromotionActionCommand', array())
    in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Form/EventSubscriber/BuildChannelBasedPromotionActionFormSubscriber.php at line 74   +

    at BuildChannelBasedPromotionActionFormSubscriber ->addConfigurationFields (object(Form), 'cheapest_product_discount', array())
    in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/PromotionBundle/Form/EventListener/AbstractConfigurationSubscriber.php at line 72   +

    at AbstractConfigurationSubscriber ->preSetData (object(FormEvent), 'form.pre_set_data', object(EventDispatcher))

    at call_user_func (array(object(BuildChannelBasedPromotionActionFormSubscriber), 'preSetData'), object(FormEvent), 'form.pre_set_data', object(EventDispatcher))

    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php at line 174   +

    at EventDispatcher ->doDispatch (array(array(object(BuildChannelBasedPromotionActionFormSubscriber), 'preSetData')), 'form.pre_set_data', object(FormEvent))
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php at line 43   +

    at EventDispatcher ->dispatch ('form.pre_set_data', object(FormEvent))
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ImmutableEventDispatcher.php at line 43   +

    at ImmutableEventDispatcher ->dispatch ('form.pre_set_data', object(FormEvent))
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php at line 341   +

    at Form ->setData (null)
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php at line 477   +

    at Form ->initialize ()
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php at line 226   +

    at FormBuilder ->getForm ()
    in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/PromotionBundle/Form/Type/Core/AbstractConfigurationCollectionType.php at line 54   +

    at AbstractConfigurationCollectionType ->buildForm (object(FormBuilder), array('block_name' => null, 'disabled' => false, 'label_format' => null, 'translation_domain' => null, 'auto_initialize' => true, 'trim' => true, 'required' => true, 'property_path' => null, 'mapped' => true, 'by_reference' => false, 'inherit_data' => false, 'compound' => true, 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => '', 'post_max_size_message' => 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.', 'error_mapping' => array(), 'invalid_message' => 'This value is not valid.', 'invalid_message_parameters' => array(), 'allow_extra_fields' => false, 'extra_fields_message' => 'This form should not contain extra fields.', 'csrf_protection' => true, 'csrf_field_name' => '_token', 'csrf_message' => 'The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.', 'csrf_token_manager' => object(CsrfTokenManager), 'csrf_token_id' => null, 'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true, 'prototype' => true, 'prototype_data' => null, 'prototype_name' => '__name__', 'entry_type' => 'Sylius\\Bundle\\PromotionBundle\\Form\\Type\\PromotionActionType', 'delete_empty' => false, 'button_delete_label' => 'sylius.form.collection.delete', 'label' => 'sylius.form.promotion.actions', 'attr' => array(), 'data_class' => null, 'empty_data' => object(Closure), 'error_bubbling' => true, 'label_attr' => array(), 'upload_max_size_message' => object(Closure), 'validation_groups' => null, 'constraints' => array(), 'entry_options' => array('block_name' => 'entry'), 'button_add_label' => 'sylius.form.promotion.add_action'))
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ResolvedFormType.php at line 126   +

    at ResolvedFormType ->buildForm (object(FormBuilder), array('block_name' => null, 'disabled' => false, 'label_format' => null, 'translation_domain' => null, 'auto_initialize' => true, 'trim' => true, 'required' => true, 'property_path' => null, 'mapped' => true, 'by_reference' => false, 'inherit_data' => false, 'compound' => true, 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => '', 'post_max_size_message' => 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.', 'error_mapping' => array(), 'invalid_message' => 'This value is not valid.', 'invalid_message_parameters' => array(), 'allow_extra_fields' => false, 'extra_fields_message' => 'This form should not contain extra fields.', 'csrf_protection' => true, 'csrf_field_name' => '_token', 'csrf_message' => 'The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.', 'csrf_token_manager' => object(CsrfTokenManager), 'csrf_token_id' => null, 'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true, 'prototype' => true, 'prototype_data' => null, 'prototype_name' => '__name__', 'entry_type' => 'Sylius\\Bundle\\PromotionBundle\\Form\\Type\\PromotionActionType', 'delete_empty' => false, 'button_delete_label' => 'sylius.form.collection.delete', 'label' => 'sylius.form.promotion.actions', 'attr' => array(), 'data_class' => null, 'empty_data' => object(Closure), 'error_bubbling' => true, 'label_attr' => array(), 'upload_max_size_message' => object(Closure), 'validation_groups' => null, 'constraints' => array(), 'entry_options' => array('block_name' => 'entry'), 'button_add_label' => 'sylius.form.promotion.add_action'))
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/DataCollector/Proxy/ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy.php at line 102   +

    at ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy ->buildForm (object(FormBuilder), array('block_name' => null, 'disabled' => false, 'label_format' => null, 'translation_domain' => null, 'auto_initialize' => true, 'trim' => true, 'required' => true, 'property_path' => null, 'mapped' => true, 'by_reference' => false, 'inherit_data' => false, 'compound' => true, 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => '', 'post_max_size_message' => 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.', 'error_mapping' => array(), 'invalid_message' => 'This value is not valid.', 'invalid_message_parameters' => array(), 'allow_extra_fields' => false, 'extra_fields_message' => 'This form should not contain extra fields.', 'csrf_protection' => true, 'csrf_field_name' => '_token', 'csrf_message' => 'The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.', 'csrf_token_manager' => object(CsrfTokenManager), 'csrf_token_id' => null, 'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true, 'prototype' => true, 'prototype_data' => null, 'prototype_name' => '__name__', 'entry_type' => 'Sylius\\Bundle\\PromotionBundle\\Form\\Type\\PromotionActionType', 'delete_empty' => false, 'button_delete_label' => 'sylius.form.collection.delete', 'label' => 'sylius.form.promotion.actions', 'attr' => array(), 'data_class' => null, 'empty_data' => object(Closure), 'error_bubbling' => true, 'label_attr' => array(), 'upload_max_size_message' => object(Closure), 'validation_groups' => null, 'constraints' => array(), 'entry_options' => array('block_name' => 'entry'), 'button_add_label' => 'sylius.form.promotion.add_action'))
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php at line 89   +

    at FormFactory ->createNamedBuilder ('actions', 'Sylius\\Bundle\\PromotionBundle\\Form\\Type\\PromotionActionCollectionType', null, array('label' => 'sylius.form.promotion.actions', 'button_add_label' => 'sylius.form.promotion.add_action'))
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php at line 106   +

    at FormBuilder ->create ('actions', 'Sylius\\Bundle\\PromotionBundle\\Form\\Type\\PromotionActionCollectionType', array('label' => 'sylius.form.promotion.actions', 'button_add_label' => 'sylius.form.promotion.add_action'))
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php at line 269   +

    at FormBuilder ->resolveChildren ()
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php at line 215   +

    at FormBuilder ->getForm ()
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php at line 39   +

    at FormFactory ->create ('Sylius\\Bundle\\PromotionBundle\\Form\\Type\\PromotionType', object(Promotion), array())
    in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Controller/ResourceFormFactory.php at line 44   +

    at ResourceFormFactory ->create (object(RequestConfiguration), object(Promotion))
    in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Controller/ResourceController.php at line 245   +

    at ResourceController ->createAction (object(Request))

    at call_user_func_array (array(object(ResourceController), 'createAction'), array(object(Request)))
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php at line 153   +

    at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), 1)
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php at line 68   +

    at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), 1, true)
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php at line 168   +

    at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
    in web/app_dev.php at line 43   +

    at require ('/Users/camerona/Documents/Projects/CheshireRaw/web/app_dev.php')
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php at line 40   +
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in CheapestProductDiscountPromotionActionCommand.

In the sylius documentation listed [here](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-promotion-action.html):

```
/**
    * {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function getConfigurationFormType()
{
    return CheapestProductDiscountPromotionActionCommand::class;
}
```

However this should be:

```
/**
    * {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function getConfigurationFormType()
{
    return CheapestProductDiscountConfigurationType::class;
}
```

This is why the code checked that CheapestProductDiscountPromotionActionCommand.php implements FormTypeInterface.

Ive managed to add my custom action and its working perfectly. There is a couple of issues with the sylius documentation but the implementation works :).